# Use a string from CoreData to set a color attribute?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm storing a 'color' item as a string in my CoreData. Is it possible to set this as a color attribute on text or a shape?

So for example, instead of this:

`.foregroundColor(Color.gray)`

Could I do something like this?

`.foregroundColor(Color string from CoreData here?)`

Comment: Why don't you store Hex string into DB?

Comment: Then you just need write a code to convert Hex string to the UIColor and UIColor to Color.

Comment: Use a dictionary. See below.

Answer (score 2):

Thera are multiple ways to achieve this requirement:

**Solution 1:**

Store Hex string into the database and convert that hex string into the `UIColor` and `UIColor` to the `Color` which you can used to show it on text or on any shapes.

**Solution 2:**

You will have to write one enum which will map the string into the `Color`

**Reference:**

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uicolor/how-to-convert-a-hex-color-to-a-uicolor

Answer (score 0):

If you have a limited number of colors you want to use, just create a dictionary which maps the String name of the color to the corresponding Color.   Then store the string to CoreData and use the dictionary to apply the required mapping when you want to use the color in your UI.

Here is an example, below. The Student entity in CoraData has 3 attributes: name (as String), hColor (as String), and id (as UUID).

```
import SwiftUI

let colorDict: [String: Color] =
["green" : .green,
 "red" : .red,
 "brown" : .brown,
 "blue" : .blue,
 "purple" : .purple
]

struct ContentView: View {
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var students: FetchedResults<Student>
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    
    var body: some View {
        // The saved hColor string is used to specify the foreground color
        VStack {
            List(students) { student in
                    Text(student.name ?? "anonymous")
                        .foregroundColor(colorDict[student.hcolor ?? "blue"])
            }
            Button("Add") {
                //generate random student names and color strings
                let names = ["Granger", "Lovegood", "Potter", "Weasley"]
                let chosenName = names.randomElement()!
                let chosenColor = colorDict.keys.randomElement()
                    
                // create a student object (including its randomly chosen
                // color string attribute) to save to CoreData
                let student = Student(context: moc)
                student.id = UUID()
                student.name = chosenName
                student.hcolor = chosenColor
                
                //save the managed object context.
                do{try moc.save()}
                catch{}
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```